# How to mock fs module together with unionfs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, fs, unionfs

I have written a test case that successfully load files into virtual FS, and at the same time mounted a virtual volume as below

```js
describe("should work", () => {
  const { vol } = require("memfs");
  afterEach(() => vol.reset());
  beforeEach(() => {
    vol.mkdirSync(process.cwd(), { recursive: true });
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

it("should be able to mock fs that being called in actual code", async () => {
    jest.mock("fs", () => {
      return ufs //
        .use(jest.requireActual("fs"))
        .use(createFsFromVolume(vol) as any);
    });
    jest.mock("fs/promises", () => {
      return ufs //
        .use(jest.requireActual("fs/promises"))
        .use(createFsFromVolume(vol) as any);
    });
    const { createFsFromVolume } = require("memfs");
    const { ufs } = require("unionfs");
    const { countFile } = require("../src/ops/fs");

    vol.fromJSON(
      {
        "./some/README.md": "1",
        "./some/index.js": "2",
        "./destination": null,
      },
      "/app"
    );

    const result = ufs.readdirSync(process.cwd());
    const result2 = ufs.readdirSync("/app");
    const result3 = await countFile("/app");

    console.log({ result, result2, result3 });
  });
});
```

By using `ufs.readdirSync`, I can access to virtual FS and indeed `result` giving me files that loaded from `disc` into `virtual FS`, `result2` representing `/app` which is a new volume created from `vol.fromJSON`.

Now my problem is I am unable to get the result for `result3`, which is calling `countFile` method as below

```js
import fsPromises from "fs/promises";

export const countFile = async (path: string) => {
  const result = await fsPromises.readdir(path);
  return result.length;
};
```

I'm getting error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app'

which I think it's because `countFile` is accessing the actual FS instead of the virtual despite I've had `jest.mock('fs/promises')`?

Please if anyone can provide some lead?

Comment: Confused as to what your objective is. You want to: >write a unit test that involves both virtual FS and actual FS. But I don't see any cases where you would need to mock anything. The first 2 results, you're using `unionfs` to read the directory files. Third result, you're using `fs/promises` to read the directory files. Neither of which needs to be mocked if, the test is to simply use `fs/promises` to read files from a virtual file system. And, `ufs` isn't mocked when using `.readdir();` but `fs/promises` does? Needs clarification.

Comment: @Tony: `countFile` is a function that uses `fsPromises`. In order to write a unit test against it, i would have to mock `fsPromises` with `unionfs` right? Because `fsPromises` doesn't access virtual FS. If it's clearer now?

Comment: A bit but, I don't understand the need to go through all this. I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you want to unit test.

```js
//CommonJS version
const fsPromises = require('fs/promises');

const countFile = async (path) => {
  const result = await fsPromises.readdir(path);
  return result.length;
};

module.exports = {
    countFile
}
```

Now, how you would normally go about this, is to mock `fsPromises`. In this example specifically `readdir()` since that is the function being used in countFile.

This is what we call: a stub.

> A skeletal or special-purpose implementation of a software component, used to develop or test a component that calls or is otherwise dependent on it. It replaces a called component.

```js
const {countFile} = require('./index');
const {readdir} = require("fs/promises");

jest.mock('fs/promises');

beforeEach(() => {
    readdir.mockReset();
});

it("When testing countFile, given string, then return files", async () => {
    const path = "/path/to/dir";
// vvvvvvv STUB HERE
    readdir.mockResolvedValueOnce(["src", "node_modules", "package-lock.json" ,"package.json"]);
    const res = await countFile(path);
    expect(res).toBe(4);
})
```

You do this because you're ***unit testing***. You don't want to be dependent on other functions because that fails to be a unit test and more integration test. Secondly, it's a third-party library, which is maintained/tested by someone else.

Here is where your scenario applies. From my perspective, your objective isn't to test `countFile()` rather, to test `fsPromises` and ***maybe*** test functionality to read virtual file-systems: `unionfs`. If so then, `fsPromises` doesn't need to really be mocked.